# Appending the contents of an xml file to another in java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have two xml files of same structure as shown below

File1:

```
<root>
<element id = "1">abc </element>
<element id = "2">efg </element>
</root>
```

File2:

```
<root>
<element id = "3">ced </element>
</root>
```

I want the resulting file as follows in utf-8 encoding

```
<root>
<element id = "1">abc </element>
<element id = "2">efg </element>
<element id = "3">ced </element>
</root>
```

Is parsing the file to appended and gettting all the element nodes using DOM parser the best method..Please Help

Answer (score 0):

This will be easiest using a modern DOM parser such as [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/).

```
SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc1 = saxBuilder.build(new File("doc1.xml"));
Document doc2 = saxBuilder.build(new File("doc2.xml"));

doc1.getRootElement().addContent(doc2.getRootElement().cloneContent());
System.out.println(new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat()).outputString(doc1));
```